# Нестандартная вёрстка блоков

Tags: html, вёрстка, css, javascript

Сломал всю голову, не могу ни как придумать как эти блоки сверстать.

Пример того, как должны выглядеть [тут больше](http://prntscr.com/3aiw7z)

[image: картинка]

Сложность в том, что эти блоки будут масштабироваться в зависимости от размера окна, а соответственно будет меняться высота и ширина каждого блока. Пробовал позиционировать каждый элемент отступами, отступы указывал в процентах, но при увеличении/уменьшении окна всё рассыпается. Думал сделать position: absolute и на JS выставлять позиции, но прикинул, что это будет очень много строк.

Буду рад любым идеям.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вот это не подойдет http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transform_rotate ?

Comment: не вижу чем мне это может помочь.
повернуть блок то легко, а вот как расположить этот блок в заданной сетке, вот это я не могу придумать

Comment: хотя нет, появилась кое-какая идея. сейчас попробую

Answer (score -1):

Однозначно нужно позиционировать с помощью `position:absolute`, а вот размеры блоков я бы задал через **calc**.